# Match alphanumeric and some special chars only regex

Tags: regex, nestjs

I am using NestJs and having some trouble with the following regex. I need to match a alphanumeric string starting with a word and allow some chars `-`, `_`, `'`

```
  @Matches(RegExp(/[\w'\-_]/), {
    message: 'provide a valid name',
  })
  name: string;
```

This allows text such as URLs to be passed in which is not allowed.

I've also tried

```
      @Matches(RegExp(/^[\w'\-_]$/), {
        message: 'provide a valid name',
      })
      name: string;
```

Adding `^`, `$` to match the exact string produces  `/^[\\w'-]$/` in NestJs console output

Expected Pass
`foo`
`foo_`
`foo-`
`foo'`

Expected Fail
`https://google.com`
`-foo`
`_foo`
`'foo`
`$foo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This regex `^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z-_']+$`](https://regex101.com/r/q2L6Vc/1) matches the conditions you've specified. (I've added unit tests to the regex based on what you've said should pass and fail)

Essentially it does the following

- Matches the beginning of the word to a letter character (not using `\w` as that includes 0-9 and `_`)
- Matches the rest of the word to the letter characters and the three you've specified (`-`, `_`, `'`)
- Matches the end of the word

This should disallow any URL as it will have a `.`, a `:` or a `//`. It should disallow any word starting with `'`, `_`, `-`, `$` or any other symbol as it won't match the `A-Za-z` condition.

I've found that `regex101.com` has been a great resource for learning, testing, and visualizing regex. Might be of help to you too

Comment: Thank you for your help on this, one of question. Will this match a single char as name? i.e. "f" as min length accepted is 1 ( I failed to mention that) and 256 as max length.  I will check regex101.com out for sure!

Comment: Change the last `+` to a `*` and it will match the single character word. I'd suggest using a secondary validator for checking the length, like class-valdiators `@MaxLength()`, as doing that with this regex would probably prove difficult, given the nature of the first matcher to be one or more